# Monodevelop on Windows 10 (no Mac) - Attempting to build using winbuild.bat results in errors (all related to Mac) AppKit, currentEvent etc

Tags: monodevelop

It seems to me that Monodevelop requires a Mac computer.  I cannot build on Windows 10 64bit.
I tried using VS2019 and winbuild.bat, both complaining about the Mac software.
Is there a way around this or do I have to use a Mac?

Comment: What kind of app are you trying to build?

Comment: Currently you are supposed to build its 7.x branch, with some patches, like I did, https://github.com/lextm/monodevelop-windows Don't waste your time on 8.x branches, as they cannot be built on Windows yet.

Comment: Ok, I can give that a try.  Now, about my question concerning Mac, is there a way not to use a Mac?

Comment: Not trying to build any app at the moment as I am struggling to get this Monodevelop to work.  I will be building an app that communicates from Monodevelop (Centos) to Linux c++ code.   I want to port a large application that currently works on Windows 10 64 bit in Visual Studio 2019 onto Monodevelop (C#) on Centos 7.